# Sequence of uniform random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables where $X_0$ is uniform in $[0,1]$ and $X_{n+1}$ is uniform in $[0,2X_n]$. Does this sequence converge to anything (in probability, a.s., $L^1$)?

I'm not sure of how to condition $X_n$ to the previous outcome $X_{n-1}$. A computer simulation seems to indicate that they should be converging to $0$ (in some sense), and that seems to be intuitive enough since it's much harder to get larger numbers and all the effort can be suddenly undone by getting a small number.

Any ideas?